# Is there a way to download the default Minecraft 1.17 textures?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make a Minecraft texture pack in 1.17 by editing the default Minecraft 1.17 textures but I don't have Minecraft. I can't download Minecraft because I am 12 and don't have money to pay for it so I searched it on Google and only found alternatives. Is there any way to download the default Minecraft 1.17 textures?

Comment: I don't think an attempt to create a texture pack without access to the game itself makes much sense. You're bound to make mistakes - everyone makes them, always, nothing like this ever works at the first try. You need the game to test your texture pack, spot and fix your mistakes.

Comment: If you still have the Mojang account, just log into minecraft.net and download the game. You still own it and you can install and play it anywhere you like, you're only not allowed to log in with the same account from multiple computers simultaneously.

Comment: If you want 1.16 textures, you could always find the textures as images [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/addons) and scroll to the bottom ([or just click here](https://aka.ms/resourcepacktemplate)) and find the bedrock ones, but they are named differently and some stuff is missing and some stuff is there that isn’t in Java, otherwise I’m not sure if you can (legally, I’m sure you could easily find some pirated ones somewhere)

Comment: I don't have a Mojang account.

Comment: The download you posted is for 1.16. Is there any similar download for 1.17?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the minecraft textures from the minecraft JAR file, you should be able to find the latest 1.17 snapshot JAR file downloads on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_21w05a).

You can then use an archive utility (like [7-zip](https://7-zip.org)) to extract the JAR and edit the textures (which are located in the `assets/minecraft/textures` folder), then just copy the folder to the place you want to make your texture pack.

Comment: Where is the JAR file on the Minecraft Wiki?

Comment: @SebastianHerb just install the game and go into the assets for the version

Comment: I can't install it but i found another source.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Default texture pack 1.17 and older versions from https://texture-packs.com/resourcepack/default-pack/